# Adding a Marker (e.g. '^') to the Start of Lines that Contain Italicized Text

Tags: parsing, replace, ms-word, formatting

Trying to set up a large (1000s of pages) text file for a parser, want to mark the start of lines that are Times, pt. 16, and italicized with a one-character symbol (e.g. '+', '*', symbols not used in rest of doc) before I convert into plaintext. Is there any way I can do this in MS Word? I understand how to find and replace all instances of a specific font with another font, or add a character to the start of individual characters of a specific font (search for ^? in the font and replace with your symbol followed by ^&. But I don't understand how to do this for a line of italicized text (vs. an individual italicized character).

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured the answer out - turns out it's pretty simple (was overthinking it).

Find: "" (empty)
Font:Times, 16 pt, Italic

Replace with: "# ^&" (if # is desired symbol)

And that's it!